# Display empty default field in Django form

Tags: django, django-templates

I would like to initialize my form with a default empty value.
In my views.py i have one like so:

```
form = BookingForm(initial={'name':''})
```

and in the template like so:

```
<tr><td><input class="input" type="text" name="name" id="id_name" placeholder="Enter your name" value={{ form.name }}/></td></tr>
```

The output however, in the html input field shows '/' instead of the placeholder.

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: You probably forgot the " " around {{ form.name}}

Comment: This is a bit confusing. The empty string is already the default, of course: what else would it be? And why are you writing the input tag HTML manually, rather than using Django to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding quotes around your `{{ form.name }}` like so:

```
<tr><td><input class="input" type="text" name="name" id="id_name" placeholder="Enter your name" value="{{ form.name }}"/></td></tr>
```

and if that doesn't change anything you can try in your `forms.py`:

```
name = forms.CharField(initial='')
```

rather than trying to set the default input value upon instantiation.